# Python 2: Conditional statement behaviour of lists with greater/smaller

Tags: python, python-2.7, comparison, conditional-statements

Can someone explain to me what is happening here?

```
>>> [] > 0
True
>>> [] > 0.1
True
>>> [] < 0
False
>>> [] < 0.1
False
>>> [] > 'string'
False
>>> [] < 'string'
True
```

Why and how does this work?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int

Answer (score 0):

So you are using Python2, where you can compare between list and strings and numbers. This helps to sort them out.

**Python2**

```
   [0]>1
=> True
```

However since Python3 this has been removed.

**Python3**

```
   [0]>1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()
```

Hope that explains, why list has been made to be greater than number is purely subjective and depends on the creators.